# Combo box to module to form not working 2nd time

Tags: vb.net, winforms

```
Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
    trapnum = trapnum + 1
    Module1.thetext = cbname.text 'room1
    room1.Show()
    Me.Hide()
End Sub

Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
    trapnum = trapnum + 1
    Module1.thetext = cbname.Text 'room3
    room3.Show()
    Me.Hide()
End Sub
```

The Room3 form will get cbname.text  value after pressing button6 and after saving going back to this form again. and trying to click button5 it will not get cbname.text to pass to room1 form.

vice versa if i click button5 first it will get and room3 will not get the value of cbname.text what do i need to do?

i cant pass cbname.text again using module1.thetext after passing for the first time. i mean my coding works only first time and i need to close my app again to work again.

Comment: Could you try to rephrase your problem? I didn't understand what you meant.

Comment: done rephrasing sir.

Comment: I've seen similar problems before... It seems that something is odd when it comes to storing variables in modules and accessing them from forms/classes. Create a class with shared variables instead and it should work.

Comment: The simplest thing would be to add `Public Property RoomText As String` to the forms

Comment: i added public property to all forms and still not working

Comment: can u give me a sample how to create a class?? @VisualVincent

never made anything in my project new to coding..

Comment: You made a Module?! Just add a new item to your project, select Class and give it a name. Open the code for your class and write your variables in there (as Shared): `Public Shared thetext As String`.